# Knexfile not reading environment variables?

Tags: node.js, docker, migration, command-line-interface, knex.js

I'm building a node/express service using docker and knex for database interaction. I have an `env_file` (defined in docker-compose file) that has some environment variables defined. The app is reading them correctly, as a `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_USER);` will log the correct value.

I followed the knex documentation to setup a knexfile that looks like so:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
      user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME_DEV,
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/migrations',
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/seeds',
    },
  },
};
```

If I hardcode the values into the knexfile, all is well. I can connect to the database, run migrations, etc.

When I use my environment variables (like above), they return undefined. Why is that?

UPDATE:

My docker compose file--`api.env` is just a basic .env file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    build:
      context: ./services/api/src/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5435:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./services/nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - api
    links:
      - api

  api:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: ./services/api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/api:/usr/src/app'
      - './services/api/package.json:/usr/src/app/package.json'
    ports:
      - 8887:8888
    env_file: ./api.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  client:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./services/client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/client:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
     - 3007:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - api
    links:
      - api
```

Dockerfile for api service:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: How are you running knex migrations? It is not shown in docker compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting environment variables correctly in your setup. Maybe you are referring env_file wrong or you might have typo in your environment variable setups.

You need to give more information how is your docker compose file etc. Your knexfile.js looks correct.

EDIT:

From your docker-compose file it looks like you are passing database connection details only to your API container. Nothing shows how are you running knex migrations and how are you passing those variables for that call.

EDIT2:

```
bash -c "sleep 10 && npm run knex migrate:latest"
```

Command opens new shell, which does not have environment variables having connection details set. You need to pass environment variables with connection details to your shell.

Probably easiest for you would be to write run-migrations.sh script, which sets and passes variables correctly before running the migrate. Like:

```
for i in $(cat api.env); do
   export $i;
done;
sleep 10;
npm run knex migrate:latest;
```

Comment: The environment variables work everywhere else in the app, just not the knexfile. But I will update my post to reflect the docker files

Comment: Maybe you are not calling knex migrate inside your container?

Comment: Also, API Dockerfile would be helpful here.

Comment: @coockoo added the Dockerfile as well

Comment: @MikaelLepistö If I run migrations outside of docker they work fine with the hardcoded values, and don't work with the environment variables.

Something like `command: bash -c "sleep 10 && npm run knex migrate:latest"` in docker-compose would have the same issues would it not?

Comment: @Jake you are creating new shell when running that bash -c and that shell does not have those environment variables set. Ofcourse it works with hardcoded values, because in that case connection details are found from knexfile.js without getting them from env. I'll update the answer

Comment: @MikaelLepistö Thanks! I ran a migrate script while in the docker container and it worked like a charm. Thanks for explaining it to me, and fixing my problem :)

Comment: I have to checkout if my shell script for reading env works like that... I didn't test it yet

Answer (score 6):

dotenv reads the vars from the files on same level as it is, so if your knexfile is not on the same directory level with you .env, you may want to set the path. Something like this:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: '../../.env' })
```

You can read the docs for more details https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv